# New Server configuration need revising?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008-r2, coldfusion

We have a web server running the following stack:

Windows 2008 R2 64Bit
Apache 2.2.25
ColdFusion 9 (32bit)
Dual Hex Core
16GB Ram

The server was pre-configured with ColdFusion 32Bit. Can we install ColdFusion 64 bit ON TOP of the 32 bit version to take advantage of more of the 16GB ram? If no one can offer any input, I do have the old development box (just slow as dirt) we can test this on but before spending the time to do it, I wanted to hear what you all had to say.

TIA,
Tom

Comment: By "ON TOP of" do you mean replace or in addition to?  I just want to be clear here.

Comment: @mdpc When I posted the question, I meant to replace so that the existing settings would remain in tact. I have since learned you can have two instances of CF installed for the sake of High Availability - that will be another question or research I need to do though.

Comment: On a test machine, I setup CF9 32Bit and configured some settings in CF Admin. Rebooted the system and then installed CF9 64Bit and not a single setting was retained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN install CF9 64-Bit on top of a 32-Bit install but you must first backup your config files first. I'd assume creating a CAR file could be created under the 32-Bit environment and then imported into the 64-Bit but that hasn't been confirmed as of right now.

Comment: If you reinstall ColdFusion 9 on top of an existing CF9 install, it can only be installed as "Multi-Server" installation only.